# Run a python command with "run" on GDB

Tags: gdb, python

Hi I'd like to run a python command `python -c 'print "\x90"*52'` when the program start in `GDB`, as I would do when I execute : `python -c 'print "\x90"*52' | ./myProg` . Does anyone knows any way to acheive this?

What I've tried so far :

- `python -c 'print "\x90"*52' ` run
- run `python -c 'print "\x90"*52' `

I really apologies if I'm not asking on the right StackExchange forum. Thanks.

### EDIT

here is a useful link I found talking about input payloads redirection : [Managing inputs for payload injection?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13928/managing-inputs-for-payload-injection?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: i ususally save the output to a file and execute "r < /file"

Comment: @Amirag I just tried this. Looks like it work just fine, thanks a lot ! Please create an answer on this topic so I can mark this topic as "answered".

Comment: See [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13928/managing-inputs-for-payload-injection/13929#13929).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not have to use another file, it is just redundant

You can do this by using "Here strings". 
In your example you can do :

```
r <<< $(python -c "print '\x90'*52")
```

You can read about "Here strings" [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)

Comment: Although this answer does provide a solution, I would love seeing an edit that takes us through the anwer and actually explain it. Naturally, there's no need to explain the python command itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of any way to run a script as a `run` argument.
A common solution is to redirect your input from a file.

You first need to run the script and save the result:

```
python -c "print 'A'*50" > my_file
```

and redirect it to gdb `run`.

```
r < my_file
```

also, from the `help run` command:

> Input and output redirection with ">", "<", or ">>" are also allowed.

which means you can also redirect output if needed.